# Insert all rows of an array into MySql table - Codeigniter-related

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm trying to enter 100 email addresses separated by ';' and store them in MySql table. What I've tried so far is:

```
    $recipient_raw = $this->input->post('recipient'); //get the 100 emails in $recipient_raw
    $recipient_array=explode(';', $recipient_raw);  //explode them into an array
    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $body = $this->input->post('body');

    foreach($recipient_array->result() as $row): 
    $recipient=array(
    'email'=>$row->email             //looping through each email; seems I should not use $row->email since there's no title for them
    );

    $this->db->insert('eamil_send',$this->db->escape($recipient));
    endforeach;
```

I'm running this on CodeIgniter PHP. Error msg is on line foreach($recipient_array->result() as $row):, where it says: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

result(), is an active record function for converting a database result object. You are creating a standard array.

```
$batch = array();
foreach($recipient as $row){
    $batch[] = array(
        'email' => $row
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('email_send', $batch);
```

That should do what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty much self explanatory..

- In the 2nd line of your code you declared $recipient_array as an Array(), not an object. So, there's no "result" method available.
  Your loop should be

  foreach($recipient_array as $row)
- On a side note, you probably shouldn't be executing db operations inside a loop (especially, for 100 operations!). Instead, you should save all the queries in one big query string and execute at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your 100 email address be separate by ',' you should use implode(glue, pieces) instead of explode() function. Like on email address that you want to insert.

```
$recipient_raw = array();
$recipient_raw[] = $this->input->post('recipient');

foreach ($recipient_raw as $value) {

        $tem_arr = implode(',', $value);
    }

$this->db->insert('eamil_send',$this->db->escape($tem_arr));
```